# What derivative to use in Gradient boosting decision tree for a semi-supervised model

Tags: gradient-descent, boosting, semi-supervised-learning

I am trying to build a semi-supervised prediction model with a Gradient Boosting decision trees. 
The learning phase is done using the following input:

1. $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p} $
2. $O(X) \in \mathbb{N}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\times 2} $ is a table of all pairwise combinations of observations in $X$, with a given ordering between them. I.e., for each pair of observations I denote which one of the pair should get a higher value of $F \left( x_{i} \right) < F \left( x_{j} \right) $ ($F
       ( 
       \vec{X_{i}} ) \in \mathbb{R} 
       $).

The loss function I use to train the model is: 
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{\left( x_{i}, x_{j}\right) \in O} L_{h}\left( 1 - \left( F\left( x_{i}\right) - F\left( x_{j}\right) \right) \right) 
\end{equation}
Where $O$ is the set of all pairs that has a known ordering between them, and $L_{h}(a) = \begin{cases} 
0 & if \, a < -h \\
\frac{(a+h)^{2}}{4h} & if \, |a| < h\\
a & if \, a > h
\end{cases} $

**My question is:** Since in gradient boosting the "outcome" variable in each iteration is defined by (and please correct me if I'm wrong): 
$$\widetilde{y_{i}} = -\left[ \frac{\partial L\left(y_{i}, F\left( x_{i}\right) \right)}{\partial F\left( x_{i} \right) } \right]$$

and in my case the loss function is based on $O(x)$, pairs ordering information, and on $X$, should the derivative that I plug into the "outcome" variable be of the shape:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial L\left( O \left( x_{i} \right) , F\left( x_{i} \right) \right) }{\partial F \left( x_{i} \right) } = -1 * \sum_{\left( x_{i}, x_{j} \right) \in O_{i} } \begin{cases} 
    0 & if \, a < -h \\
    -1 * \frac{\left( a + h \right) }{2h} & if \, |a| \leq h \\
    -1 & a > h 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $a = 1 - \left( F\left( x_{i}\right) - F\left( x_{j}\right) \right) $
and thus its derivative is $\frac{\partial a}{\partial F\left( x_{i} \right) } = -1$

That means, that the value of the derivative for observation $i$ is the sum of the loss function derivative overall pairs that include observation $i$. If so, then I count twice each pair? Once for the $\widetilde{y}_{i} $ and once for $\widetilde{y}_{j}$?

On the other hand, can I update the outcome variable at stage $m$ to be $F_{m}(x_{i}) - \widetilde{y}_{m-1}$ ? While the error term is calculated based on the actual loss function I want to use?

**TL;DR** In gradient boosting decision trees, if my loss function is not a function only of $\hat{y}_{i}$, but rather take in account a comparison of all of the observations pairs combinations (i.e. $\hat{y}_{i}, \hat{y}_{j}$ were $i \neq j$. Then the residual at iteration $m$ is still $  \frac{\partial L\left( O \left( x_{i} \right) , F\left( x_{i} \right) \right) }{\partial F \left( x_{i} \right) }$  (where $O(x_{i})$ is the information I have on all pairs taht $x_{i}$ belong to) **?**